# Calculating interest rate

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> The interest rate of deposit is 0,30 at
>   the beginning of a year and 0,5 at the end.
>
> Find the profit of deposit of 20 000$.

Could you help me?

Comment: Do you need help in finding the quadratic function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadratic follows the format:

$f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$

Now we know $f(0)=0.15$, $f(0.5)=0.1$ and $f(1)=0.08$. Plugging these into our original formula, we get $3$ equations with $3$ variables. If you can solve this to obtain $A$, $B$ and $C$, you have found your quadratic equation. To solve them, you should try substitution.

---

$f(0)=A \cdot 0^2+ B \cdot 0+C$
$0.15=C$

So now we can write $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+0.15$.

$f(0.5)=\frac A4+\frac B2+0.15=0.1$
$A+2B=-0.2 \tag 1$

$f(1)=A+B+0.15=0.08$
$A+B=-0.07 \tag 2$

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$:

$B=-0.13$

Substituting this into $(2)$,

$A-0.13=-0.07 \implies A=0.06$.

Therefore $f(x)=0.06x^2-0.13x+0.15$

Comment: Like this? $ p*e^{\int_{0}^{0}0,15ds},

 p*e^{\int_{0}^{0,5}0,1ds} ,

 p*e^{\int_{0}^{1}0,8ds} $

Comment: Umm no. I will update with an exact solution.

Comment: Sorry, LaTeX is refusing to work. Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much!